# to check the multiple of five and two

Tags: c++

#include

```
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  int multiple;
  cout << "Please give a number you want to check the multiple of: ";
  cin >> multiple;
  if ((multiple % 5 == 0), (multiple % 2 == 0));
 
    {           
      cout << multiple << " is multiple of five. " << endl;
      cout << multiple << " is the multiple of two. ";
    }
    
  else {
    
      cout << multiple << " is not multiple of five. " << endl;
      cout << multiple << " is not the multiple of two. ";
    }
    

  return 0;
}
```

I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement.
I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement. I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement. I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement. I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement. I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement. I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement. I can't find the error in the code. It shows error in the else statement.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the syntax you have been taught.

Comment: `if ((multiple % 5 == 0), (multiple % 2 == 0));` -- Instead of guessing what to do, you should be learning from a good C++ book.  A good C++ book would never show anything to what you wrote here.  This also shows that inventing things, like using a `,`, will many times be compilable, but will do something totally different than what you expect.  That's why you cannot guess when learning C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows an error in the else statement because C++ doesn't expect a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of your if statement.

When C++ sees a `;` your if-statement is considered done. It has no effect — it just skips it.

Also, your if-syntax is wrong. It shouldn't have a comma `,`.

This should be what you intended to do:

```
if (multiple % 5 == 0 && multiple % 2 == 0) {
  cout << multiple << " is a multiple of five. " << endl;
  cout << multiple << " is a multiple of two. ";
}
else {
  cout << multiple << " is not a multiple of five. " << endl;
  cout << multiple << " is not a multiple of two. ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in line

```
if ((multiple % 5 == 0), (multiple % 2 == 0));
                       ^                     ^
```

It should be

```
if ((multiple % 5 == 0) || (multiple % 2 == 0))
```